# ros melodic unment dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, ros, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to install ros melodic on ubuntu 18.04 following instructions in this page http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu,
when I use this command `sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full` I get the following message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-melodic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-melodic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install ros-melodic-desktop but it keeps giving me dependencies error messages.
Any help, please.

Comment: have you already tried `sudo apt install -f` (just like that)? If that doesn't fix it then check your apt sources to make sure you still have the ros repo. And of course run a `sudo apt update` to make sure the package list is up to date.

Comment: See: https://answers.ros.org/question/243920/how-to-install-ros-kinetic-ubuntu-1604/

Comment: I tried all of that but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

if this doesn't work then just reinstall ubuntu. That's a faster way of get rid of these issues.